# Serilog: How do I further enhance a filter expression in appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I have two loggers with Serilog and they save to different files. I want to create the loggers through the appsettings.json as opposed to code.

When I create my loggers through the `Startup.cs` configuration, I get a much more specific log and I prefer to have it that way as it's much clearer and will allow others to check the logs and understand what's going on without needing much technical knowledge. However, I want to apply this to the appsettings so that I can migrate the code to any other project that I may use.
*FYI: I don't want to override the log level.*

For example, with code I create my loggers like so:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
    .WriteTo.File("Serilogs/Program_log_.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information))

    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
    .WriteTo.File("Serilogs/ServerTrace_log_.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information))

    .CreateLogger();
```

This generates the two separate outputs that I like the formatting of:
`File 1`: Readable, custom logs:

```
2019-01-18 11:18:09.873 +00:00 [INF] //Some custom log information
2019-01-18 11:18:09.875 +00:00 [INF] //Some more custom log information
```

`File 2`: Stack trace, server information:

```
2019-01-18 11:17:56.378 +00:00 [INF] User profile is available. Using '//A path' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
2019-01-18 11:17:57.840 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html  
2019-01-18 11:17:58.074 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 235.5796ms 200 text/html
2019-01-18 11:17:58.326 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json  
2019-01-18 11:17:58.452 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 126.2127ms 200 application/json;charset=utf-8
```

When I do it by using the JSON appsettings it looks like so:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Filters.Expressions",
      "Serilog.Settings.Configuration"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "SourceContext = 'Microsoft'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "./Serilogs/server_logs_.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "SourceContext = 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "./Serilogs/program_logs_.log",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this generates the two files.
`File 1`: Readable, custom logs:

```
2019-01-18 11:22:52.903 +00:00 [INF] User profile is available. Using '// A path' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
2019-01-18 11:22:59.229 +00:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "PollForStatusUpdate", controller = "StatusMessage"}. Executing action {apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname})
2019-01-18 11:22:59.505 +00:00 [INF] Executing action method {apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname}) with arguments (["{apiname}.{controller}.{method}.MessageResult"]) - Validation state: "Valid"
2019-01-18 11:22:59.632 +00:00 [INF] //Some custom log information
2019-01-18 11:22:59.639 +00:00 [INF] //Some more custom log information
{apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname}), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 516.8129ms.
2019-01-18 11:23:00.040 +00:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type '{apiname}.{controller}.{method}.MessageResult'.
2019-01-18 11:23:00.048 +00:00 [INF] Executed action {apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname}) in 813.08940000000007ms
```

`File 2`: Stack trace, server information:

```
2019-01-18 11:22:52.903 +00:00 [INF] User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\msharp\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
2019-01-18 11:22:54.263 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html  
2019-01-18 11:22:54.473 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 211.831ms 200 text/html
2019-01-18 11:22:54.737 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json  
2019-01-18 11:22:54.838 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 100.8892ms 200 application/json;charset=utf-8
2019-01-18 11:22:59.205 +00:00 [INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://localhost:5001/api/StatusMessage/PollForStatusUpdate application/json-patch+json 180
2019-01-18 11:22:59.229 +00:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "PollForStatusUpdate", controller = "StatusMessage"}. Executing action PureValuationsApi.Controllers.StatusMessageController.PollForStatusUpdate (PureValuationsApi)
2019-01-18 11:22:59.505 +00:00 [INF] Executing action method {apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname}) with arguments (["{apiname}.{controller}.{method}.MessageResult"]) - Validation state: "Valid"
2019-01-18 11:22:59.632 +00:00 [INF] //Some custom lof information
2019-01-18 11:22:59.639 +00:00 [INF] //Some more custom log information
{apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname}), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult in 516.8129ms.
2019-01-18 11:23:00.040 +00:00 [INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type '{apiname}.{controller}.{method}.MessageResult'.
2019-01-18 11:23:00.048 +00:00 [INF] Executed action {apiname}.{controller}.{method}.PollForStatusUpdate ({apiname}) in 813.08940000000007ms
2019-01-18 11:23:00.052 +00:00 [INF] Request finished in 847.5964ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

So, by applying what feels the same technique, the outcome of the results are different as `File 1` now contains more action information and `File 2` contains the stack *plus* the custom log information although I want them completely separate.

Comment: side note if this is dotnet core - the `using` block for serilog is optional

Answer (score 8):

I think your filters are not quite right.

The filter expression should be :

```
"expression": "SourceContext = 'Microsoft' or StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.')"
```

(I guess you could just do `StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft')` without the last dot , but then that may not behave properly for namespaces like `MicrosoftOrIsItReally.MyNamespace`)

(internally `Matching.ForSource` does a `SourceContext.StartsWith(..)` kind of filtering , as seen [in the source](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/e638941551d353dbc588f0f21ab397d5d259de43/src/Serilog/Filters/Matching.cs#L42-L47))

To confirm it, you may want to edit the `outputTemplate` of your File sink to display the `SourceContext` property and see the origin of the log events. (the default is `"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"`) . You could change it to `"{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}]<{SourceContext}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"` to include the `SourceContext` property.

---

By the way, you have an extra, unneeded `"Using"` directive. The `"Serilog.Settings.Configuration"` is not necessary

Comment: `> "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'Microsoft.')"` The result of this seems to be the equal to the way I did it, I have altered to conform to how the standards should be. Thanks for this. If only they did the same thing or you could qualify multiple filters

Comment: my bad, I think you should do both "equal" Microsoft, or Starts with Microsoft (with a dot) ... I'll update my answer

Comment: Still not behaving the exact same, which I'm finding weird as going through the method it feels like it's the same thing?

Comment: Are you properly using exactly the same expression in both filters (once `includingOnly` and once `excluding`) ? weird !

Comment: `"Name": "ByIncludingOnly",` and `"Name": "ByExcluding",` Any alternative seems to break it in such way that it will duplicate logs for both `File 1` and `File 2`

Comment: That looks like a bug then ... you might want to file a bug in the repo so more people can look at it and see something I may have missed. (you can add details to the existing issue : https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions/issues/30 )